# Check a model attribute multiple times inside the business logic

Tags: javascript

We have a situation where we need to check a model attribute multiple times inside the business logic.

```
eg: if(this.model.attributes.AcmeData.attributes.isEmpty){
    }
```

this check will happen multiple times. Should check this object multiple times or should we store it in a local variable to be used in multiple locations, like:

```
var acmeDataFlag = this.model.attributes.AcmeData.attributes.isEmpty;
```

and then check this variable multiple times.

For me, the creation of a local variable is more expensive than checking that object multiple times.

Comment: this is a question that would get better responses from [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Be warned, however, they will likely have the same criticism of the question there that I have:  "Multiple times" is subjective (that could mean 5, or could mean 100), and it doesn't give enough information to reasonably know what making this kind of change would have.  On top of that, there are many other factors at play;  how big the function is, how often the attribute will change, how often the function is called, etc.  IMO, this isn't an answerable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much more readable and understandable if you create a variable with a speaking name, IMO. Functions with several `this.model.attributes.AcmeData.attributes.isEmpty` are harder to read.

If this isn't really high performance code, the downside of creating another variable is negligable in favor of the improved readability.

Comment: Your question is very opinion-based so you can get opposite answers. But best practices usually advice to create variable with obvious names instead of long properties chains...